# Make app configurable for different customers

Tags: php, linux, web-applications, yii2

I'm trying to come up with a tactic for making a fairly standard web-based application configurable on a per-customer basis, so we can sell it multiple times without having to write extra code for each customer. It's a LAMP stack (where P is php with yii2)

My initial idea is to have a JSON/YAML file per-customer, and turn on/off features based on what's in that. something like {hasAmazonApi : 0, hasEbayApi: 1} etc.

The problem with that is, of course, lots of if/else in the code.

My boss has suggested that the config file could be used to actually control what code is deployed on the server at deployment time, writing a script to write the code - but that seems fraught with difficulty and danger.

Neither solution is perfect - any suggestions?

Comment: We've decided (well, I decided and sold it to my boss) and have gone with something a little different.

What I've settled on is a little like hooks. Each element of workflow will happen with a function which will be kicked off by run_hook('some-func', $args).

That way, we can override each hook on a per-customer basis, or just use the generic one if that suits their needs better.

It's more complicated, but leaves us with far fewer if/else-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We mostly handle this in two ways:

1. We make one application with one database (one codebase) and separate all the users by a RBAC system with custom rules (ie. user should belong to this organisation to control this project). In your case: User should have bought this module to use it.
2. We make one application with one codebase. But every client gets their own database. So the user can only see the data in his own database (he can never "switch" to another database).

Of course there are other ways. Based on your needs and the amount of roles you expect you pick one that feels good for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no right or wrong answer really but your first option is probably preferable, as long as you have full access to where the code is deployed to and customers don't have access to change the config and opt in to things they've not paid for.

You're right to be wary of doing a partial deployment. It'll be much easier to develop and test the application if it's all in one piece and configuration dictates what users can do. You run the risk of things breaking in difficult to figure out ways, and potentially suffer from inability to reuse code effectively.

Yii2 modules may lend themselves to the latter approach if the features could be separated into modules like that. For the above reasons I'd only do that as a last resort. From your examples it sounds like that won't be possible in any case (eBay/Amazon credential inputs would probably be within the same module, alongside each other in the UI).

Comment: actually, the credentials for ebay/amazon will be in a db, not hard coded.